# Summing up collections.Counter objects using `groupby` in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, python-collections

I am trying to group the `words_count` column by both `essay_Set` and `domain1_score` and adding the counters in `words_count` to add the counters results as mentioned here:

```
>>> c = Counter(a=3, b=1)
>>> d = Counter(a=1, b=2)
>>> c + d                       # add two counters together:  c[x] + d[x]
Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 3})
```

I grouped them using this command:
`words_freq_by_set = words_freq_by_set.groupby(by=["essay_set", "domain1_score"])` but do not know how to pass the Counter addition function to apply it on `words_count` column which is simply `+`.
Here is my dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupBy.sum` works with Counter objects. However I should mention the process is pairwise, so this may not be very fast. Let's try

```
words_freq_by_set.groupby(by=["essay_set", "domain1_score"])['words_count'].sum()
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 1, 2], 
    'b': [Counter([1, 2]), Counter([1, 3]), Counter([2, 3])]
})
df

   a             b
0  1  {1: 1, 2: 1}
1  1  {1: 1, 3: 1}
2  2  {2: 1, 3: 1}


df.groupby(by=['a'])['b'].sum()

a
1    {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1}
2          {2: 1, 3: 1}
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Comment: Approximately have 13K rows, took ~ `26` seconds. Thank you so much! It worked.

Comment: @White159 that's piss poor, and also expected. If you're having performance trouble consider exploding your dictionaries. With the right data representation this operation could take a fraction of a second.